# Howto update an ARGO-CD parameter via REST-API?

Tags: rest, parameters, overriding, argocd

I found the swagger-ui., but the only functionality I can imagine to do this job (I found) was the application patch method (swagger-ui#operation/Patch). But I find no explanation how to do it.

The explanation I found is for the cli tool of argocd (https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/parameters/) which does not really help me.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet........

Comment: I am not sure what parameters you want to override. In my case I wanted to update targetRevision. I was able to do this after updating the spec and synching the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of adopting GitOps is to use Git as a single source of truth.If you want to change your application with ArgoCD you are expected to commit your change to the Git repository watched by ArgoCD.

Changing manually values via REST APIs is against GitOps.

Answer (score 1):

Kazanki's answer does not address the question. While I agree that it may be an "anti-pattern", there are still times when this is desirable.  For example, not wanting to maintain multiple sets of helm charts that would be identical other than for a single value (in my case, the ingress hostname).

This update can be done using `argocd` cli.  Example:

```
argocd app set <appname> -p ingress.hostname=<new value>
```

I've yet to find out how to do this with REST but would very much like to know as well.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can do this using Argo CD [api client libraries](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/v2/pkg/apiclient) for go. I'm not sure if there are client libraries for other languages though.